# Banner Image covers side cart in ecommerce story. How to prevent this?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have an issue with the side cart and I'm sure my CSS is incorrect, so maybe you can help me to figure it out.

I have a background image on the page, a full width banner. But when I open the side cart, the image goes over it. It covers the content inside the side cart.

Here's the page: http://innovo-medical.com/pages/about-innovo-medical

Click on cart to open side cart and see the issue

HTML is simply

CSS:

```
#header-image {
    background-image:url("{{ 'Ladyinblue Copy.jpg' | asset_url }}");
    width: 8980px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -3999px;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Please help me identify the mistake if possible!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `width`, also you have a container `width: 1200px`, don´t use in the image if you want the image goes horizontal full screen.

```
#header-image {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/Ladyinblue%20Copy.jpg?12631246775371885148");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 0 10px -3999px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Image full width technique

```
<div class="container"> your header </div> // close container
<div id="header-image"></div>
<div class="container main content"> // open container again
<div class="sixteen columns clearfix collection_nav">
  <h1 class="collection_title">
    About Us
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="sixteen columns page">
    <p style="text-align: left;"><a href="http://innovo-medical.com">Innovo Medical</a>&nbsp;is a privately-held company located in Stafford, TX primarily involved in the design and manufacturing of <a href="http://innovo-medical.com">Medical Products</a>. The company was born out of frustration with companies cutting corners in the name of corporate profit. We believe that medical equipment&nbsp;should be reliable, safe and simple to use.</p>
<p>Customers’ feedbacks are the backbone of every product we launched. Our products have been wildly successful because we take every single customer’s feedback seriously. If you have any concerns or questions with our product, please contact our customer service team. We listen and We deliver. That is our promise.</p>
<br>
<div style="text-align: left;"><a title="Innovo Google Plus: Innovo Groups Medical Supplies" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+Innovogroups/posts"><span>Interact with Innovo on Google+</span></a></div>
<div style="text-align: left;"><a title="Innovo Facebook - Innovo Groups - Medical Supplies" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/InnovoG/">Like Innovo Products on Facebook</a></div>
<div style="text-align: left;"><a title="Innovo Twitter: Innovo Groups Medical Supplies" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/InnovoG">Follow Innovo Medical Equipment on Twitter</a></div>
<div style="text-align: left;"><a title="Innovo Pinterest: Innovo Groups Medical Supplies" target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/innovomedical/">Pin Innovo Medical Supplies&nbsp;on Pinterest</a></div>
<div style="text-align: left;"><a title="Innovo LinkedIn: Social Media | Medical Supplies | Innovo Groups" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/10252810">News and Headlines from Innovo on LinkedIn</a></div>
<div style="text-align: left;"></div>
<div style="text-align: left;">More reviews at Innovo Google+ and Innovo Facebook pages</div>
<div style="text-align: left;"></div>
<div style="text-align: left;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: Instead of  copy the code, try to understand it

Comment: That worked to a certain extent. I have now made your changes go live. The background image is not full width now. On the right side it's missing part of the background....

Comment: Sorry, not really understand. What is your recommendation? Do I change container width to 100% or 1980px? How do I get it to go across full screen.

Comment: @InnovoMedical I edit again with a simple technique - (close container before image and open again after image)

Comment: Yes. It's almost perfect. But I still cant figure out why the right side is covering the rest of the picture which white background. http://innovo-medical.com/pages/about-innovo-medical

Comment: No...this was just an example...i see that you replicate the code. What you need to do is to close the existent container and open it again after the image...lol

Comment: I edit again with your code for better understanding

Comment: I just changed the container width to 100% and the image shows up now. Just gotta figure out how to center every page's content again. Im truly sorry if I am causing you troubling. Trying to learn as I go.

Comment: Don´t mess with the width container...i already explain..it´s not to hard to understand (close and open again a div)

Comment: Okay. its done. THanks again for your patience! and input!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have found so far:

- In Google Chrome 47, I added a style `overflow:hidden;` to the `<div class="nm-page">`, and it worked as you mentioned;
- In Firefox 40, clicking in "Cart" doesn't show your cart even after adding the same style;
- In Firefox 24 and Chrome 34, it worked as it is.

Comment: I think the problem is that my container width is 1200px and I want it to be full width. But I do not know the code to "center" content.... in other words, container full width while page content is centered